# What code/tool do I need to make the line at 1.20 green to show a threshold?

Tags: delphi, teechart

[image]In the chart below I want to show the data at line "1.20" as the threshold form upper limits of normal.  How is this accomplished.  The line will ALWAYS be a different color no matter how the data values changes.

I have googled but everything seems to change the color of the line segments. I just want to change that one and only line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a second series that is all the same value without visible points.

[image]

Comment: can you please point me to a tutorial on how to do that.  I am using a DBChart.  Is adding a second series just using another instance of the sqlite query but not showing the data points? I am still learning how to use Charts. Thanks

Comment: Add another column to your query for the threshold value. Then add a series and hook that up the same as you did the current series but with the Y the column with the threshold value. Steema do have the documentation available online : http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/tutorials/

Comment: I'll take a look at that and come back if I still can't figure it out.  Thanks

Comment: The values listed are pulled from a table of many other values.  Not sure if I can add a threshold value based on that.  The data comes from Table "Labs", restricted to "Serum creatinine" so I get a query result with just creatinine values. How to add another column in that instance?

Comment: Add a constant value column to the SQL query. For example `SELECT Name, Age, 21 as ThressholdAge FROM PEOPLE;` the third column is a constant or static value.

Comment: Thanks.  Have to step away for a while to run an errand. I will give it a shot when I return and report back.  Again, thanks for your guidance and help.

Comment: Thank you.  Adding the threshold value and hooking up as a second series did exactly what I needed.